# Refining Convex Hull to Find Better Enclosing Shape of Point Cloud

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, convex-hulls, envelope

I have a $2D$ point cloud that I am trying to find the border of. I have created the convex hull of the points,

[image: Convex Hull]

But I would like to find a better enclosing line segments or possibly a curve that defines the shape of this blob. I could convert these points to an image grid and use an image segmentation algorithm but I would lose accuracy and performance would be slow.

I worked with optimization before, I know machine learning algorithms, which approach could I use to define a better contour for this shape? One idea I had was iterating through all convex hull segments, from midpoint scan inward, if there are empty regions between segment and points, break segment into two create two segments each connecting to outermost point of the point cloud. I am basically trying to reach something like this (roughly jotted the left side only);

[New Borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GxFN.png)

Comment: What would you _like_ the "border" of those points to be? If you can't define that, then we can't really help you. What are you going to use it for?

Comment: I added new image, see the red lines

Comment: So how would you define your new red border? I'm not trying to be awkward, I just think that you might not realise the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: Sure. The line pieces of the border should be as close to points as possible; similar to SVM support vectors, except there are no -1 label points, only +1 points (the point cloud). I cant define it beyond that, can it be tied to a parameter which can be adjusted?

Comment: There is a so-called One Class SVM approach, I used it but did not work well on all points. I am almost tempted to use a mini-version of it on each subproblem I mentioned above, for making convex hull segments move closer to the points.

Comment: See this for instance: http://duckham.org/matt/characteristics-shapes/

Comment: In some formulations, this is an NP-hard problem. See https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2017.08.014

Comment: See also https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cag.2022.08.002